# EPERM after restarting the media application

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I have a user space media application written in C.

This application works in redundancy mode so that if a server fails, the standby server answers all calls.

I encountered an issue with the sendto syscall that returns errno EPERM after the following scenario happens:

*At the beginning the main server is up and running, handling the media calls*

1. Restart the application of the main server to simulate a server failure;
2. At this moment the standby server answers all calls;
3. Restart the application of the standby server to simulate a server failure;
4. At this moment the main server answers all calls and the sendto syscall returns EPERM.

I disabled all rules from iptables to ensure that neither port is blocked.

Any thoughts on what could cause this error?

Comment: the sendto syscall in which server process?

Comment: @user253751 Following the above example, the application of the main server is up and running, while the sendto syscall return errno EPERM.

Comment: the sendto syscall in which process?

Comment: @user253751 do you ask about the process id? When the application is restarted, the process id is changed and assigned by the os.

Btw, the application is single thread.

Comment: No I ask which process. You say you have a main server process and a standby server process and of course there is also a client process. All of these processes are calling sendto. Which one is causing the problem?

Comment: There is only one application running on a server. By server, I mean a physical machine that runs Linux. The application is a user-space application so that Linux assigns to it a process id. In redundancy mode, there are two servers, one main and one standby. Only one server is handling the media calls. If the server running the calls fails, the other server takes over the calls.

Comment: **and which one gets errors when it calls sendto?**

Comment: The application from the main server, but in a certain scenario that was described at the beginning.